Does the concept “let history be the judge” apply to controversial figures in Judaism?
There have been numerous figures who have generated controversy across Jewish history as to whether their views or claims were within the pale of Judaism. Often, these figures faced opposition in their lifetimes from even a majority of rabbis or communities. Examples range from the Rambam to Abraham Abulafia to Rabbi Luzzato to Rabbi Yonatan Aibeshutz to the Lubavitcher Rebbe.
Does the fact that they are accepted nowadays by “mainstream Judaism” (an admittedly ambiguous term), settle the controversy definitively, like some sort of “divine nod”?
So, for example, if the historical opponents would have foreseen that their adversary would one day be accepted, would they have conceded their opposition? And conversely, is this an argument against modern-day belligerents, that their opponent has been accepted by mainstream Judaism, so they should just be quiet?
Note: I am asking about Jewish historical imperative regarding individuals, not movements (such as Hasidism).
I am looking for sources that discuss this please.

Most non-Hassidim would tell you that Hassidism is now a valid form of Judaism, even if that wasn't so simple 220 years ago.

Another example from the fairly recent past: Rav Yonatan Eybeschutz

@JoelK nice one. I'll put it in

Check out the concept of "Catholic Israel"

What was the controversy with Ramchal and that Abraham rabbi?

@Curious check out Wikipedia. Weird stuff.
